# NetworkStream readed message checking

Tags: c#, networkstream

From Server i sending "100"

```
NetworkStream sStream = Client.GetStream();
string sMessage = "100";
byte[] sM = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sMessage);
sStream.Write(sM, 0, sM.Length);
```

and my Client have this code.

```
sStream.Read(sM, 0, sM.Length);
string FirstCall = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(sM);
// or even 
string FirstCall = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(sM).ToString();
if(FirstCall == "100")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Message check.. Message : "+Encoding.ASCII.GetString(sM));
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error ; " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(sM));
}
```

End i getting message box says - Error ; 100

At this point i do not know what i missing.. if i already do 
`Encoding.ASCII.GetString(sM)` it should be a string.

Comment: Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's impossible to say for sure what all the bugs in your code are. But based on the tiny bit of code you shared, I'd say the main issue is that you are converting an array of bytes longer than the bytes you actually read, resulting in extra data in your output string (probably a bunch of `'\0'` characters), so the string equality comparison fails. Use the value returned by the `Read()` method, and be prepared to have to read multiple times in order to get all the bytes that were sent.

Comment: (Oh, and...calling `ToString()` on a `string` object is pointless.)

Comment: Your lesion was quite lazy, but thank to your argument i did research about bytes.. and i figure out how to make script more safe and sort the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duo my research about bytes, i figure out.., if i want to send and receive 3 digits number i need do `byte[] data = new byte[3];` - "*use byte size 3 as sending 3 digit number*" and then `sStream.read(data, 0, data.Lenght);` ..

Or if Sending text, but text each time is different bytes, to remove `\0` after text can use `var new_data = data.TakeWhile((v, index) => data.Skip(index).Any(w => w != 0x00)).ToArray();` but i do not test out if it remove `\0` between bytes what you want to keep.